# How can I ensure that the latest version of my javascript code is loaded for the client?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching, browser

We have a client with thousands of users (who all use Internet Explorer) and a large amount of javascript files that enhance their user experience with our product.

The problem I'm having is that any time we update one of these scripts **there is no way to know whether the client is seeing the latest version**. What we're having to do is tell our client to **do a hard refresh** (ctrl+f5) before viewing any changes. Obviously this approach is not ideal.

I know that browsers cache based on the url, so one could use something like

```
<script src='myScript.js?ver=1.2'>
```

to get around the issue, but this is not an option for us.

I was hoping that there's some kind of header property or something similar that we could use to tell IE not to cache these scripts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is that not an option for you?  Adding a `ver` querystring is a pretty standard way to accomplish that

Comment: Incidentally, why is fingerprinting not an option?

Comment: It IS technically an option, but because of the way our system is set up, it's not a great one. If there is no other way around it, we'll likely have to find a good way making that work. I was wondering about any alternatives, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need to know about cache http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL <-- HTTP Headers

Answer (score 3):

You can also version the filename itself like jQuery does:

```
<script src='myScript-v1-2.js'>
```

Then, each time you revise the script, you bump the version number and modify the pages that include it to point to the name of the new script.  This is foolproof vs. caching, yet still allows your viewers to receive the maximum benefit of caching and requires no server configuration changes for the .js file.

A full solution will typically include setting a relatively short cache lifetime for your host web page and then allow the various resources (stylesheet files, JS files, images, etc...) to have longer cache lifetimes for maximum caching.  Anything that is fingerprinted can have a very long cache lifetime.  See [the reference](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL) that fabianhjr posted about for ways to set the cache lifetime of the host web page.  It can be done in the web page itself (`<meta>` settings) or in the http headers via the server.

If you turn off caching for your script file (which would likely have to be done at the web server level for a script file) then all your viewers will lose the performance benefit of caching and you will lose the bandwidth and load-saving benefit of caching.  If you use a common .JS file across many pages (a common design pattern), your viewers will see slower performance on every page.

Comment: With the fingerprinting approach in general, doesn't it still depend on the header not having been cached?

Comment: @Maxx - The fingerprinting approach only depends upon the host web page not being cached for too long and you have to either implement fingerprinting for that too or set some sort of cache control setting on the host web page.  The ideal scenario is usually a relatively short cache lifetime on the host web page and long cache times for most of the resources which are fingerprinted.  This gives you quick access to changes, but long caching for the larger resources.

Comment: You can also do versioning without changing the file name by adding a parameter like this: `<script src='myScript.js?version=2016-02-14'>`

Comment: @BSMP - Yes, you can do it that way too, but that requires specific server support to return the proper script that matches the version number.